# Returning mode day only if criteria is met

Tags: google-sheets

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15_PYwwUR6K9s3Jl6eEoH06E_S_8H21HZJFbkqP-HPVY/edit?usp=sharing

I am trying to find the mode day in range 'B2:B' from sheet 'Day Test'! and return value in sheet 'Return Mode Day'! in B2
If a row has blank value this should be excluded
If a new row if added it should include this data also
I need it to calculate based on specific cell value ie. C2:C = "A"

The following formula pretty much works for all data but doesn't include the condition C2:C = "A"

```
=INDEX(IFERROR('Day Test'!B2:B5,MODE(MATCH('Day Test'!B2:B5,'Day Test'!B2:B5,0))))
```

Help please?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to return, for each `Partner`, which weekday appears more often?

Comment: Correct, if we can do it for one it will be easy to change for the rest though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) to get the dates with the corresponding partner.
- Use [WEEKDAY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092985?hl=en) to change the dates to numbers.
- Use [MODE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094029?hl=en) to get the most repeated number.
- Use [TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139) to get the weekday name.

```
=IFERROR(TEXT(MODE(ARRAYFORMULA(WEEKDAY(FILTER('Day Test'!A$2:A,'Day Test'!C$2:C=A2,'Day Test'!A$2:A<>"")))),"dddd"))
```

[image]

#### Note:

In the sample above, the cell remains empty if there are no dates with this partner, or if no weekdays occur more than once (as `MODE` works). I'm not sure whether you want a different behavior for these edge cases.

Comment: Thank you so much @lamblichus ah the edge cases aren't a problem as the data set will be so large for this. It works perfectly when I apply it live :)